# Difference between upper and lower case double (float) type specifiers in C

Tags: c, types, double, format-specifiers

In C double/float has a set type specifiers: `%f` `%F` `%g` `%G` `%e` `%E`. Is there any difference between

- `%f` and `%F`,
- `%g` and `%G`,
- `%e` and `%E`?

According to `printf` and `scanf` the output is equal. Then why both upper and lower cases are valid?

Note that type specifiers for scanf double are starting with lowercase `l`

Comment: *The F conversion specifier
produces INF, INFINITY, or NAN instead of inf, infinity, or nan,
respectively.*

Comment: [This `printf` (and family)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) and [this `scanf` (and family)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/scanf) references should tell you everything you need to know.

Comment: The E specifier produces an uppercase Exponent (I.e. 10.2E+3). The specifier G uses E or F format instead of e or f.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
specifier   Output  Example
d or i  Signed decimal integer  392
u   Unsigned decimal integer    7235
o   Unsigned octal  610
x   Unsigned hexadecimal integer    7fa
X   Unsigned hexadecimal integer (uppercase)    7FA
f   Decimal floating point, lowercase   392.65
F   Decimal floating point, uppercase   392.65
e   Scientific notation (mantissa/exponent), lowercase  3.9265e+2
E   Scientific notation (mantissa/exponent), uppercase  3.9265E+2
g   Use the shortest representation: %e or %f   392.65
G   Use the shortest representation: %E or %F   392.65
a   Hexadecimal floating point, lowercase   -0xc.90fep-2
A   Hexadecimal floating point, uppercase   -0XC.90FEP-2
c   Character   a
s   String of characters    sample
p   Pointer address b8000000
n   Nothing printed.
The corresponding argument must be a pointer to a signed int.
The number of characters written so far is stored in the pointed location.  
%   A % followed by another % character will write a single % to the stream.    %
```

[The Source of above](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/)

Answer (score 8):

The difference between `%f` and `%F` are if they print infinity and NaN as lower case or upper case. Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){
    printf("%f and %f\n", INFINITY, nan("0"));    //Prints "inf and nan"
    printf("%F and %F\n", INFINITY, nan("0"));    //Prints "INF and NAN"
    return 0;
}
```

`%f` and `%F` are identical when printing real numbers. For example, `printf("%f", 1.0)` and `printf("%F", 1.0)` do exactly the same thing.

Note that `%F` is only available in C99 or C++.

The difference between `%e` and `%E` is if the "e" that separates the number and the exponent is lower or upper case (for example `1.0e+0` or `1.0E+0`. It also makes a difference for infinity and Nan just like for `%f` and `%F`. Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){
    printf("%e, %e and %e\n", INFINITY, nan("0"), 1.0); //Prints "inf, nan and 1.0000e+00"
    printf("%E, %E and %E\n", INFINITY, nan("0"), 1.0); //Prints "INF, NAN and 1.0000E+00"
    return 0;
}
```

The difference between `%g` and `%G` is that `%g` takes the shortest between `%e` and `%f`, and `%G` takes the shortest between `%E` and `%F`.